# Git - restore a deleted folder from previous commit

Tags: git

I have a git repo on my local and I push it to BitBucket.

I have a deleted folder in my previous commit, which I now want to bring it back.

On my local machine, I do

```
git checkout COMMIT_ID path/to/deleted/folder
```

and I got

```
error: pathspec path/to/deleted/folder did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Any advice?

Comment: Restore a file, not a directory. Git only manages directories as part of tree objects.

Comment: @CodeGnome, true, but you if you specify a directory path, Git will restore the files within.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A cause of the error is likely to be that you're trying to checkout the directory from a revision it didn't exist in. Are you absolutely positive that in `COMMIT_ID` the directory existed?

By the way, the command should be

```
git checkout COMMIT_ID -- path/to/deleted/folder
```

Comment: ok I tried adding the --, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: try `git fetch` before the checkout.

Comment: this is weird, I tried all 4 of the previous commit IDs, in which the folder exists - (I can see it!)... but it's keep giving me the same error.

Comment: even trying individual files within that directory, but no luck.

Comment: if you do `git ls-tree -r COMMIT_ID` can you see the directory listed?

Comment: crap - sorry, so while I was trying different thing, I was trying to checkout from one of the sub folders, not in the project root directory.. worked now. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to your current working directory. The path parameter is relative to your working directory. So cd to the root directory of your git repository and use a path relative to the root of the git repository.